# SQL query in C#, Invalid object name 'userInfo'

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

```
SqlConnection scon = new SqlConnection(arthurDBConnectionString);
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
da.InsertCommand = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO userInfo VALUES(@firstname, @lastname)", scon);
da.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@firstname", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = firstname;
da.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@lastname", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = lastname;

scon.Open();
da.InsertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery(); <--Exception(Invalid object name)
scon.Close();
```

First off I would like to say that I am new to SQL. I am working on an application in C# that will manipulate data on a SQL Server. Above is the code I have for adding data to two columns of a table but I get the error that 'userInfo' (the table) is an invalid object name. I have made sure that this table exists in the database and that the connection is Open. I have also tried referring to the table as
`DATABASENAME.SCHEMA.userInfo` and `SCHEMA.userInfo` with the same results. Thanks in advance for any help or input.

Comment: Try just dbo.userInfo. Oh: you did create the table, right?

Comment: Sounds like the table name is wrong. Are you sure it's correct?

Comment: Don't you also need the field names before the VALUES? e.g. `INSERT INTO userinfo (firstname, lastname) VALUES (@firstname, @lastname)`

Comment: @JasonDown no - it will assume that you are setting values for all columns in that case.

Comment: I suppose that you are not connecting to the correct server. Check your connection string and look at the database used by the connection

Comment: Most of the time it will be a better practice to always put the schema name in front of the object name.  INSERT INTO userInfo ..... convert to INSERT INTO dbo.userInfo ...... that of course if dbo. is the correct schema.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are getting that error then there is NOT a 'userInfo' table in your scope.  Try logging in with management studio and using query analyzer to run the same command.  Make sure you use the same login information in arthurDBConnectionString, debug your method and hover over it to make sure you are using the same information that is causing the error.

1) If your collation is case sensitive (check with `SELECT SERVERPROPERTY('COLLATION')`), the capitalization of 'userInfo' must be identical.

2) Are you in the right database?  Maybe your connect string mis-spells the property (i.e. `INITIL CATALOG=dbname`, try another command in your code `SELECT db_name()` to make sure.

3) Is the schema the same?

4) Do you have permission to select from the table?

Answer (score 1):

Check,
1)Check the table you have created exist in same data base that you provided in connection string.
2) Cross check table name

Comment: thank you, forgot to change database name in connection string

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this

```
da.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@firstname", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = firstname;
da.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@lastname", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = lastname;
```

use this

```
da.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@firstname", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = textBox1.Text;
da.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@lastname", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = textBox2.Text
```