# How to resolve Invalid Object Name "Table Name" in C#?

Tags: c#, sql-server

When I am running My application in Visual Studio 2008 it is showing me Message Box with notation of Invalid Object Name "Table name", instead the table is already there in my database. So please help me to solve this problem.

```
private void FrmInwardDisp2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  byte _true = 1;
  byte _false = 0;
  //this.toolTip1.SetToolTip(this.dgvDisplay, "Double Click to Edit");
  int width = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width;
  int height = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height - 175;
  dgvDisplay.Width = width - 25;
  dgvDisplay.Height = height;
  //dgvDisplay.AutoSize = true;

  try
  {
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(Variables.con);
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    cmd.Connection = con;

    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    da.SelectCommand = cmd;

    switch (Static_Class.selected)
    {
      case 1:
      {
         btnAddInward.Text = "Add Rental Inward";
         cmd.CommandText = "SELECT [RentalInwardNo],[VoucherNo],[NameOfWork]
         [Location],[NameOfVendor],[VendorCode],[VendorItemCode],[ItemName],
         [Narration],[WareHouse],[DriverName],[VehicleNo],[RejectedItemCode],  
         [RejectedItemName],[Rate],[Date],[InvoiceNo],[ChallanNo],[TenderCode],
         [PINo],[PONo],[UnitQty],[UOM],[RequisitionNo],[ReceivedBy],
         [LocationID],[Layer],[Local],[Global],[DeleteStatus],[AutoGenerated] 
         FROM IN_Rental_Inward 
         where [TenderCode]= " + Static_Class.tendercode + " 
         and [LocationID]='" + Static_Class.LocationID + "' 
         and [Layer]='" + Static_Class.Layer + "' 
         and [DeleteStatus]=" + 0;

         try
         {
           //con.Open();
           da.Fill(ds, "TableDisplay");
           da.Dispose();
           cmd.Dispose();
           //con.Close();
           dgvDisplay.DataSource = ds.Tables["TableDisplay"];

         }
         catch (Exception ex)
         {
           MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
         }
      }
      break;
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read the [faq] and [ask]. You could also take the [tour]. After you've done this, please edit your question properly.

Comment: Can you show some code ?

Comment: post some code so that we can help :)

Comment: I copied your title into Google and found the following stack overflow answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15911503/sql-query-in-c-invalid-object-name-userinfo

Comment: I had tried This link but is it not working in my code

Comment: You are only interested in one DataTable so don't use a Dataset take just a DataTable. Your DataAdpater has a Fill override that take a DataTable directly no need to use a DataSet.

Answer (score -1):

In your query text, specify the table's schema name also before the table name. For example:

```
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT … FROM dbo.IN_Rental_Inward …";
//                               ^^^^
```

Comment: I had tried with schema.table name but it is not working